# Normalization of a database schema

Tags: database, database-normalization

Here are the relationships between 3 objects - A, B and C.
A:B - 1:M
A:C - 1:M
B:C - M:M, with the restriction that they must share the same A instance.

My current schema is as follow.
a (id, data)
b (id, a_id, data)
c (id, c_id, data)
b2c (b_id, c_id)

How to design a better schema to avoid data inconsistency?

I know the title of this post is kind of general. If any of you can think of a better title, fell free to edit this post.

---

As an example, I am going to develop an app for generating an ad wall. An ad wall is divided into many `sections`. Each section has a `dimension` (width and height). There are many `ads`, each of them also has a dimension. Think of an ad can show on multiple sections, and a section can has multiple ads rotating. So the relationship between sections and ads is many-to-many, but with the restriction that they must has the same dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a business rule that should be enforced in code. Section:Ad as M:M is already normalized.

However, I'm not sure you need a `Dimension` table, if that's what you're thinking as the 'A' table in your example.

Comment: Correct. I need a `dimension` table to avoid inputting several combinations of width/height over and over. The `dimension` table is the `A` table.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. But I still think Section:Ad is M:M, that's just a fact about the schema. Trying to change the schema to enforce a business rule is not a good idea.

Comment: I realized you could probably use database triggers (or maybe a check constraint) if you really wanted the DB to enforce your rule. I can't say whether or not this is a good idea, but I'm going to guess that it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You're already defining the B:C relationship with these two relationships:
A:B - 1:M
A:C - 1:M

I don't see why you need a B:C relationship table.

---

Given your example, I only see two tables.  Ads have a width and height, but there's a 1:1 relationship, so width and height are just fields in the ads table.  Sections also have a 1:1 relationship to width and height.  Only two tables.  I don't see a strict relationship between ads and sections, either.

Comment: I need the B:C relationship table because not all B's and C's that has the same A can map to each other. In my example, a section can has multiple ads with the same dimension as the section itself, but NOT all ads with that dimension can show on that section.

Comment: Ah, I see.  The A table still seems unnecessary then.  I'd move the dimensions to each table instead of defining a circular relationship.

Comment: If I move the dimensions to each table, then when I map ads to sections I have to check if they have the same width and height instead of the same dimension_id. Still, when I change the dimension of one section, it will invalidate the relationship for all ads that map to that section. So there will be data inconsistency. Seems that this kind of data consistency can only be enforced by code but not database schema.

Comment: Oh, I think the consistency works just fine in the DB.  You have Ad, Sections and a M:M relational table.  In your M:M table you put in check constraints to make sure that Ad.width = Section.width and Ad.height = Section.height.  Now you can't make a relation in M:M that's invalid.  Now, to see potential matches, you create a VIEW which is `SELECT Ad.ID, Section.ID WHERE Ad.width = Section.width AND Ad.height = Section.height`.  You can make the VIEW more complex and not show records in your M:M table, but I can't do that one off the top of my head.  Many/1/null to many/1/null is hard.